# Call reference of an object as a parameter in another method

Tags: c#

For example:

```
A a = new A(b);
B b = new B(a);
```

How can I use `b` as a parameter in `A` constructor when it's not existed, how can the compiler will know that `b` will be created later?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

In `A` class add public method like `Init(B b)` and call it after you create the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
class StrongReference<T> { public T Target; }
var rb = new StrongReference<B>;
A a = new A(rb);
rb.Target = new B(a);
```